# how to stream a large directory to a HTTP server via CURL put?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, tar, curl

I have a large directory that I want to upload to a remote server using only `tar` and `curl`. I don't need any compression as the directory already contains compressed data.

here is the command I am working with -

```bsh
tar cf - /dir/*  | curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" https://server/ --data-binary @-
```

when `dir` is large, I see that OOM killer kills the process.
I would have expected the output of tar to be streamed and the curl to upload the file in a steaming manner but that's not happening as after a few seconds the command gets killed.

Comment: HTTP upload cannot be 'streamed' unless the server is HTTP/1.1 and implements 'chunked', or HTTP/2, either of which the client can only know by remembering a previous response. `curl` only does a single request/response and does not have any previous reponse to remember, so it can't stream.

Comment: thanks, please post it as an answer and I will accept it